# Is it safe to add a node to a CockroachDB cluster while an IMPORT command is active on the cluster?

Tags: import, cluster-computing, cockroachdb

I would like to add a node to my CockroachDB cluster, but the cluster is currently undergoing an IMPORT. Would it still be safe to add a node while the IMPORT is active?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a node during an active IMPORT should be completely safe. Currently it'll be ignored by the running import as far as processing the importing data, though our key-value storage layer may start to rebalance imported data on to the added node.